# What are differences in purposes and contents between ECMA-335 and ISO/IEC 23271:2012 as CLI standards?

Tags: c#, clr

[ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) and [ISO/IEC 23271:2012](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=58046) are both CLI standards.

The former is free, and the latter isn't.

1. What are differences between  them in their purposes?
2. What are differences between  them in their contents?

   In the forward of ECMA-335,

   > The ECMA-335 Standard is fully aligned with ISO/IEC 23271:2012.
   >
   > The following features have been added, extended or clarified in the
   >   Standard:
   >
   > The following changes of behavior have been made to the Standard:
   >
   > The following types have been added to the Standard or have been
   >   significantly updated

   By comparing their tables of contents, I feel [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) and [ISO/IEC
   23271:2012](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec23271%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf) are basically the same.

Thanks.

Comment: No differences afaik, I seriously doubt many here spent two hundred bucks to make sure.  It was submitted as a [fast-track process to ISO](https://www.ecma-international.org/news/ECMA%20ISO%20CSharp%20Final.pdf).  So it would be up to ECMA to respond to any objections and make the voters happy.  That can be quite a soap opera, the sordid details around [Ecma-376](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardization_of_Office_Open_XML) are an interesting read.  No such upheaval around 335.

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant. I was looking for the official reference for CLI Standard Libraries, so I bumped into CLI standards. But in ECMA standard for CLI, the part for Standard Libraries is very short. Do you happen to know the official references for CLI Standard Libraries and some good books on them? Thank.s

Answer (score 2):

Actually they are both free. You can get the ISO standard from ISO for free from [here](http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/c058046_ISO_IEC_23271_2012(E).zip).

Apart from the copyright notice and the forward, they are both identical. As PDF documents, the ISO has a nice table of contents (ToC) while the ToC in the ECMA one is just gibberish.